# Wires outside running to meter box are loose

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, electric-heat

Somebody keeps messing with my wires to my meter box. They were just running my furnace and lights after the 1st sabotage. Now nothing works, but when the wind blows we can see the lights flicker on and off. Advice please!

Comment: what is your specific question? ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Pictures would be nice.

Comment: Calling the power company (see manassehkatz's answer) is absolutely, positively, the very first thing that should be done!

Answer (score 6):

There are two possibilities here:

- An actual "Somebody" messing with your wires

Call the police. *Also call your electric utility.* Because even if it is actual sabotage, the electric utility is the organization that will fix it, not the police. (Not the fire department either. Several years ago after a 2-foot snowstorm there was a burning transformer on a pole. Fire department came, made reasonably sure that the fire was contained to the transformer, put caution tape around the pole and left it for the electric utility to fix, which they did pretty quickly. Fire department had bucket trucks that could reach, but not the training and equipment to safely disconnect and certainly not to repair.)

- Loose connections caused by storm damage and/or long-term damage due to weather

This is *very* common. Call your electric utility. Tell them you have a *dangerous* situation. All the wires from the street to your meter are normally under control of your utility, even if you technically own them. That is, the utility doesn't want you messing with them for safety reasons, and for that reason they will normally check and repair them at no charge. The wires from your meter to your panel are normally very short and far less likely to be damaged by the weather.